# NDSolve issue with initial and boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method

While solving the heat equation in one spatial variable $u_t = u_{xx} $  (x goes from 0 to L) with the initial temperature distribution $T_0 \frac{x(L-x)}{L^2}$ , and with neumann boundary conditions $u_x(0,t) = u_x(L,t) = 0$, I got some really weird behaviour from NDSolve.

My code looks like this:

```
h[x_] := x*(30 - x)/900;
pde = D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x]
begin = 0;
end = 30;
bc = {u[0, x] == 100*h[x], (Derivative[0, 1][u])[t, begin] == 
    0, (Derivative[0, 1][u])[t, end] == 0};
finaltime = 100

s = NDSolve[{pde}~Join~bc, u, {t, 0, finaltime}, {x, begin, end}];
```

Since heat cannot flow out through the ends, continuing this in time should yield a smoothening until it reaches the average everywhere. Instead, I get a very weird time evolution which when plotted seems to be of the form $u_x(x,t) = u_x(x,0) - kt$. This is particularily infuriating because the problem seems to be intermittent. Taking the square of h does not cause any trouble.

The problem seems to magically fix itself if I instead feed in a truncated cosine series into the code:

```
rule = t -> FourierCosSeries[t*(2*Pi - t), t, 35];
f[x_] := (t /. rule) /. (t -> x)
g[x_] := f[2*Pi*x/30]/(4*Pi*Pi)
```

and insert g instead of h into the code above. Trying a function interpolation gave only errors.

Is there a fix which is more general than this quick hack?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the finite element method with the method of lines as [@toadatrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/120/toadatrix) suggested, but for the FEM method to work, you need to do a little more.  The Neumann boundary conditions need to be specified using [`NeumannValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html).

```
h[x_] := x*(30 - x)/900;
op = D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x];
begin = 0;
end = 30;
bc = {u[0, x] == 100*h[x]};
neumann = NeumannValue[0, x == begin] + NeumannValue[0, x == end];
finaltime = 100;

s = NDSolve[{op == neumann, bc}, 
   u, {t, 0, finaltime}, {x, begin, end}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" ->
    {"MethodOfLines", {"SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}}
   ];
```

The default boundary condition is `NeumannValue[0,...]`, so you could just simply use `op == 0`.

Check the result:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[u[t, x] /. s // Evaluate, {t, 0, finaltime}, {x, begin, end}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.5], 
   InfinitePlane[{0, 0, Integrate[100*h[x], {x, 0, 30}]/30}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}]
 ]
Show[%, ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   *The graphs shows that the temperature evens out to the average over time.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all you need to do is select the following method option in NDSolve

Method->{"PDEDiscretization"->{"MethodOfLines",{"SpatialDiscretization"->"FiniteElement"}}}

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Did you try this? I get an error. (V10.2.)